# rank $2$ bundle being an extension of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $\geq 2$. Fix an ample divisor $H$ and let $E$ be a $\mu$-semi-stable vector bundle of rank $2$ with $c_1(E)=0$. Assume $H^0(E)\neq 0$. I am looking for a proof of the following statement:

If $0\neq s\in H^0(E)$ vanishes no where, then $E$ is an extension of line bundles.

My attempt: Suppose such a section exists, then we have a surjection from $E^*\to \mathcal{O}_X$ (this follows from the definition of section of vector bundle), but I do not know how to proceed from here.

Thanks!

Comment: If such a section exists (with no further assumptions), we have $\mathcal{O}to E$ given by this section. The cokernel is a line bundle $L$, since the section is nowhere vanishing. So, the vector bundle is an extension of $\mathcal{O}$ and $L=E/\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you explain a little more on why the section is no where vanishing implies the cokernel is a line bundle?

Comment: If $s\in H^0(E)$ is nowhere vanishing for a rank $r$ vector bundle $E$, then the cokernel is a (rank $r-1$) vector bundle. This is a local checking. Locally, $E$ is a free module and nowhere vanishing section means $s$ is part of a basis of $E$ by Nakayama's lemma. Thus, the cokernel is a free module.